# Call an event from a base class

Tags: c#, events, inheritance

I have the following scenario:

```
public abstract class SomeBaseClass
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;

    ...
}

public class SomeClass : SomeBaseClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //TODO

        if (SomeEvent != null)
            SomeEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

`SomeBaseClass` has an event which needs to be called in a base class, however this it isn't possible to directly call the event from a base class. To get around this, I can override the event in the base class, like so:

```
public class SomeClass : SomeBaseClass
{
    new public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
```

This is fine I guess, however my question is whether there is some kind of universal method, or *good practice* for implementing the functionality above?

The fact that it isn't possible to call an event from a base class suggests that I shouldn't really be doing this in the first place, perhaps the responsibility of calling the event should be only in `SomeBaseClass`?

Comment: did you try  `SomeEvent(base, EventArgs.Empty);`?

Comment: AFAIK, Events are not inherited, so you can't raise the event directly from the derived class, but you can write a protected method in the parent class that will raise the event when called, and call it from the derived class using `base.RaiseMyEvent(new EventArgs())`

Comment: @KhanhTO Yep, I got the error: *"Use of keyword 'base' is not valid in this context*"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That isn't allowed indeed. If I may recommend an alternative approach:

```
public abstract class SomeBaseClass
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;

    protected void RaiseSomeEvent(EventArgs e)
    {
        var eh = SomeEvent;
        if (eh != null)
            eh(this, e);
    }
}

public class SomeClass : SomeBaseClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //TODO
        RaiseSomeEvent(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Note that I have moved the invocation of the event handler to the owning class, this is required by .NET / C# since only that class can invoke the event handler. Second, I have made the event handler thread safe by assigning it to `eh` first.

**Never** hide the base class' event by using the `new` keyword! You will get unexpected results when you use the base class' type as type for a variable or when the base class invokes the event.

Comment: In [C# 6.0](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#null-conditional-operators) thread-safe event rising is a "simple" `SomeEvent?.Invoke(this, e);`

Comment: @Sinatr that is nice indeed. Thanks for the useful comment.

Comment: Is there no way with no boilerplate?

Answer (score 3):

I would stay away from using `new` mainly because code will behave differently if an object is cast to the base class. Here's an alternative implementation:

```
public abstract class SomeBaseClass
{
    public virtual event EventHandler SomeEvent;

    protected virtual void HandleSomeEvent()
    {
        var ev = SomeEvent; // Localize event field used
        if (ev != null)
        {
            ev(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

public class SomeClass : SomeBaseClass
{
    public override event EventHandler SomeEvent
    {
        add { base.SomeEvent += value; }
        remove { base.SomeEvent -= value; }
    }

    protected override void HandleSomeEvent()
    {
        base.HandleSomeEvent();
        // ... My own code here
    }
}
```

This allows for a great deal of flexibility. You can provide some implementation of event handling as well as allow the implementer to completely override the base class implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
public delegate void ErrorHandler(string result);
public class BaseClass
{
   public event ErrorHandler OnError;
   protected void RaiseErrorEvent(string result)
   {
     OnError?.Invoke(result);
   }
 }
public class SampleClass:BaseClass
{
   public void Error(string s)
   {
     base.RaiseErrorEvent(s);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to use delegates for that :

```
   public abstract class SomeBaseClass
    {
        public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
        protected Action<object, EventArgs> SomeEventInvoker;

        public SomeBaseClass()
        {
            SomeEventInvoker = new Action<object, EventArgs>((sender, args) => 
             { if (SomeEvent != null) SomeEvent(sender, args); });
        }
    }

   public class SomeClass : SomeBaseClass
    {
        public SomeClass()
        {
            DoSomething();
        }

        public void DoSomething()
        {                
            SomeEventInvoker(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
```